# A segmentation error in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am working on creating a C program to implement lists into a binary file and I received a segmentation error after the compilation.
This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>


#define LONG_NP 30

struct Personne {

    char nomPre[LONG_NP+1];

    char sexe ;

    float taille, poids ;

};


struct Elem {

    struct Personne pers ;

    struct Elem * suivant ;

};


typedef struct Elem * pointeur ;
typedef struct Elem Element;

void lire(FILE * aLire, struct Personne * P) {

    struct Personne unePers ;

    fgets(unePers.nomPre, LONG_NP+1, aLire) ;

    fscanf(aLire,"%c%f%f\n", &unePers.sexe, &unePers.taille,

                  &unePers.poids);

    *P = unePers;

}



void creerFIFO(pointeur * P) {



    pointeur laListe = NULL, tempo, presentement;



    FILE * aLire = fopen("metrique.tp3", "r");

    while (! feof(aLire)) {

        tempo = (pointeur) malloc ( sizeof (struct Elem));

        lire(aLire, &tempo->pers);

        if (laListe == NULL)

              laListe = tempo ;

        else

              presentement->suivant = tempo;



        presentement = tempo;

    }

    fclose(aLire);

    if (laListe) presentement->suivant = NULL;

    *P = laListe;

}



void afficher(pointeur liste, char ordre[]) {

    printf("Contenu de la liste en ordre %s\n", ordre);

    while (liste) {

        printf("%s %c % 7.2f %8.1f\n", liste->pers.nomPre,

            liste->pers.sexe, liste->pers.taille, liste->pers.poids);

        liste = liste->suivant;

    }

}



void creerBinaire( pointeur liste, char * nomFile) {

    FILE * aCreer = fopen(nomFile, "wb");

    int nbOctets = sizeof(struct Personne);

    if(!aCreer)
        printf("Fichier pas ouvert\n");

    while (liste) {

        fwrite(&liste->pers, nbOctets, 1, aCreer);

        liste = liste->suivant;

    }

    fclose(aCreer);

    printf("Fin de la creation du fichier binaire\n");

}



void relire(char nomFile[]) {

        FILE * aLire = fopen(nomFile, "rb");

        struct Personne unePers ;

        int rang = 0, nbOctets = sizeof(struct Personne);



        while ( fread(&unePers, nbOctets, 1, aLire), !feof(aLire))

            printf("%2d) %s %c % 7.2f %8.1f\n", ++rang,

                unePers.nomPre, unePers.sexe, unePers.taille, 

                    unePers.poids);



        fclose(aLire);



}




/* écrivez vos fonctions ici avec, en commentaires, le numéro de la
   question de l'examen à laquelle elles répondent.
*/


/* Question 6 */

void chercherNom(pointeur Liste, pointeur *Av, pointeur *CL, char Nom[])
{

    pointeur Avant = NULL;
    int trouve = 0;
    while (Liste && !trouve)
    {  
        if(strcmp(Nom, Liste->pers.nomPre)!=0)
        {
           Avant = Liste;
           Liste = Liste->suivant;
        }
        else
            trouve = 1;
    }

    *Av = Avant;
    *CL = Liste;
}


void Changer(struct Personne * A, struct Personne B)
{
      struct Personne Tempo = *A;

      if(strcmp(Tempo.nomPre, B.nomPre) !=0)
         strcpy(Tempo.nomPre, B.nomPre);

      if(B.sexe != ' ')
          Tempo.sexe = B.sexe;

      if(B.taille > 0 )
          Tempo.taille = B.taille;

      if(B.poids >0)
          Tempo.poids = B.poids;

      *A = Tempo;

}





void cherModif(pointeur Liste, char Nom[], struct Personne Pers)
{

    pointeur Avant, CL;
    struct Personne Tempo;


    chercherNom(Liste,&Avant, &CL,Nom);

    if(CL)
    {
        Tempo = CL->pers;
        printf("trouve %s\n",Tempo.nomPre);
        Changer(&Tempo,Pers);
        CL->pers = Tempo;
    }
    else 
        printf("pas trouve %s\n",Nom);
}



void CreerLIFO(pointeur Liste, pointeur *P, char sexevoulu)
{
    pointeur L = NULL;
    pointeur Tempo;


    while(Liste)
    {
        if(Liste->pers.sexe == sexevoulu)
        {

          Tempo = (Element *) malloc( sizeof(Element));

          Tempo->pers = Liste->pers;


          Tempo->suivant = L;

          L = Tempo;

        }


        Liste = Liste->suivant;
    }




    *P = L;
}



void main() {

/* Écrivez les déclarations des 2 nouvelles listes ici */
   pointeur ListeF, ListeM ;


   pointeur liste ;

   /* question 6 */

   struct Personne Tempo;
   char NomTempo[LONG_NP+1];
   creerFIFO(&liste);

   afficher(liste, "FIFO");

   /* Écrivez les appels de la fonctions de la 
      question 6 ici, le bon résultat sera observé
      avec la relecture de metrique.bin
   */


   strcpy(Tempo.nomPre,"BEDARD MARC-ANDRE             ");
   Tempo.sexe = 'M';
   Tempo.taille = 1.54;
   Tempo.poids = 0;

   cherModif(liste,Tempo.nomPre,Tempo);

   strcpy(NomTempo,"TREMBLAY CYLVAIN              ");

   strcpy(Tempo.nomPre,"TREMBLAY SYLVAIN              ");
   Tempo.sexe = ' ' ;
   Tempo.taille = 0;
   Tempo.poids = 0;

   cherModif(liste,NomTempo,Tempo);




   creerBinaire(liste, "metrique.bin");

   relire("metrique.bin");


   /* Écrivez les appels pour la question 7 ici */

    CreerLIFO(liste,&ListeF,'F');
    CreerLIFO(liste,&ListeM,'M');




   /* Pour tester, écrivez 2 appels de la fonction
      afficher : */
        afficher(ListeF,"LIFO");
        afficher(ListeM,"LIFO");

}
```

I am using the GCC as a compiler, and I didn't get any fault with compilation, the problem occur when I tried to excite the Output file with the command ./a.out and here I got the Fault with no more specifications .
So the question is,how to solve the segmentation fault problem, because I am not seeing it in the code yet.

Now after the debug I find this :

```
Starting program: /root/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at /root/Desktop/tp/liste.c:282
282    creerFIFO(&liste);
(gdb) s
creerFIFO (P=0x7fffffffe2d8) at /root/Desktop/tp/liste.c:54
54      pointeur laListe = NULL, tempo, presentement;
(gdb) s
58      FILE * aLire = fopen("metrique.tp3", "r");
(gdb) s
60      while (! feof(aLire)) {
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7aa4230 in feof () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Which means that I am having a problem with the while function

Comment: Where do you get the Segmentation Fault error? Please label more or less where it occurs so future users don't have to read _all_ of the code and instead just the more relevant parts.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am using the GCC as a compiler, and I didn't get any fault with compilation, the problem occur when I tried to excite the Output file with the command ./a.out and here I got the Fault with no more specifications .

Comment: So, debug your program, and fix the bugs once you have found them.

Comment: After starting the debug, I find this :
Starting program: /root/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at /root/Desktop/tp/liste.c:282
282    creerFIFO(&liste);
(gdb) s
creerFIFO (P=0x7fffffffe2d8) at /root/Desktop/tp/liste.c:54
54  pointeur laListe = NULL, tempo, presentement;
(gdb) s
58     FILE * aLire = fopen("metrique.tp3", "r");
(gdb) s
60  while (! feof(aLire)) {
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7aa4230 in feof () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Comment: This is the worst code i ever met. Change your job please.

Comment: It seems crashing after calling `feof`. Check if `aLire` isn't `NULL` (the file is successfully opened).

Comment: I created two empty files `metrique.bin` and `metrique.tp3` then ran the program with gdb. I used gcc 4.8.2 and -g3 option. My gdb sayd that the program exited with code 042 but reported no Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Note: You shouldn't use `void main()`, which is implementation-defined. One of standard main function is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your file* `aLire` is a `nullptr`

You should check the return value of `fopen` before using it for `feof`. When I try to run your code I see to get an error similar to yours, because I do not have a file "metrique.tp3" on my system. 
Are you sure you have one (and at the same path as the executable you try to run)?

I don't mean to offend you, but from your code I think you have not done a lot of coding. At least not in C/C++. Some pointers that may be helpful to you:

1. Test the return variables of system calls. You should always do this, but especially when the function returns a pointer.
2. Always check if pointers are not null before you use them
3. Initialise your variables. I see a lot of pointer declarations without initialization. If you do not initialise a pointer, a subsequent check to see if it is a null pointer will often be useless as the pointer will likely get a random value.
4. If you allocate memory (malloc, calloc, etc) you should deallocate it once you are done with it. I see a malloc() in your code, but I don't see a free() anywhere.
5. A good IDE can help you a lot, especially when you start coding. If you run this executable in a debugger, it will show you exactly where your segmentation error occurred and you will be able review the contents of all your variables. In this case, that would have immediately pointed you to aLire being a null pointer. I am not sure on which platform you are working. For windows, there is a free version of visual studio available which includes all the tools you need. If you are on another platform (or just don't want to use microsoft's compiler), I have always liked to work with Eclipse's CDT, but it has been some years since I have worked with that, so it may have been superseded by other IDEs.
6. Finally, you are of course free to use any language you want, but if you use English for your variable and function names, it is a lot easier for us non-French speakers to understand what your intention is and therefore to help you.

Answer (score -1):

I modified a little bit the function `lire()`,
now it is working correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define LONG_NP 30

struct Personne {

    char nomPre[LONG_NP+1];

    char sexe ;

    float taille, poids ;

};


struct Elem {

    struct Personne pers ;

    struct Elem * suivant ;

};


typedef struct Elem * pointeur ;
typedef struct Elem Element;

/*___________________________________________________________________
*/
void lire(FILE * aLire, struct Personne * p) {

    if(!p) {
        printf("lire: Persone *p est nulle");
        return;
    }

    fgets(p->nomPre, LONG_NP+1, aLire) ;

    fscanf(aLire,"%c%f%f\n",
           &(p->sexe), &(p->taille),&(p->poids));

}
/*___________________________________________________________________
*/


void creerFIFO(pointeur * P) {

    pointeur laListe = NULL, tempo, presentement;

    FILE * aLire = fopen("metrique.tp3", "r");

    if(aLire) {
        while (! feof(aLire)) {
            tempo = (pointeur) malloc ( sizeof (struct Elem));

            lire(aLire, &tempo->pers);

            if (laListe == NULL)
                laListe = tempo ;
            else
                presentement->suivant = tempo;

            presentement = tempo;
        }

        fclose(aLire);
    } else {
        perror("creerFIFO");
    }

    if (laListe) presentement->suivant = NULL;

    *P = laListe;

}

/*___________________________________________________________________
*/

void afficher(pointeur liste, char ordre[]) {

    printf("Contenu de la liste en ordre %s\n", ordre);

    while (liste) {

        printf("%s %c % 7.2f %8.1f\n", liste->pers.nomPre,

               liste->pers.sexe, liste->pers.taille, liste->pers.poids);

        liste = liste->suivant;

    }

}


/*___________________________________________________________________
*/
void creerBinaire( pointeur liste, char * nomFile) {

    FILE * aCreer = fopen(nomFile, "wb");

    int nbOctets = sizeof(struct Personne);

    if(!aCreer)
        printf("Fichier pas ouvert\n");

    while (liste) {

        fwrite(&(liste->pers), nbOctets , 1, aCreer);

        liste = liste->suivant;
    }

    fclose(aCreer);

    printf("Fin de la creation du fichier binaire\n");

}

/*___________________________________________________________________
*/

void relire(char nomFile[]) {

    FILE * aLire = fopen(nomFile, "rb");

    struct Personne unePers ;

    int rang = 0, nbOctets = sizeof(struct Personne);


    while ( fread(&unePers, nbOctets, 1, aLire), !feof(aLire))

        printf("%2d) %s %c % 7.2f %8.1f\n", ++rang,
               unePers.nomPre, unePers.sexe, unePers.taille,
               unePers.poids);


    fclose(aLire);

}

/*___________________________________________________________________

    écrivez vos fonctions ici avec, en commentaires, le numéro de la
    question de l'examen à laquelle elles répondent.

    Question 6

*/
void chercherNom(pointeur Liste, pointeur *Av, pointeur *CL, char Nom[]) {

    pointeur Avant = NULL;
    int trouve = 0;
    while (Liste && !trouve) {
        if(strcmp(Nom, Liste->pers.nomPre)!=0) {
            Avant = Liste;
            Liste = Liste->suivant;
        } else
            trouve = 1;
    }

    *Av = Avant;
    *CL = Liste;
}


/*___________________________________________________________________
*/

void Changer(struct Personne * A, struct Personne B) {
    struct Personne Tempo = *A;

    if(strcmp(Tempo.nomPre, B.nomPre) !=0)
        strcpy(Tempo.nomPre, B.nomPre);

    if(B.sexe != ' ')
        Tempo.sexe = B.sexe;

    if(B.taille > 0 )
        Tempo.taille = B.taille;

    if(B.poids >0)
        Tempo.poids = B.poids;

    *A = Tempo;

}



/*___________________________________________________________________
*/

void cherModif(pointeur Liste, char Nom[], struct Personne Pers) {

    pointeur Avant, CL;
    struct Personne Tempo;


    chercherNom(Liste,&Avant, &CL,Nom);

    if(CL) {
        Tempo = CL->pers;
        printf("trouve %s\n",Tempo.nomPre);
        Changer(&Tempo,Pers);
        CL->pers = Tempo;
    } else
        printf("pas trouve %s\n",Nom);
}

/*___________________________________________________________________
*/

void CreerLIFO(pointeur Liste, pointeur *P, char sexevoulu) {
    pointeur L = NULL;
    pointeur Tempo;


    while(Liste) {
        if(Liste->pers.sexe == sexevoulu) {

            Tempo = (Element *) malloc( sizeof(Element));

            Tempo->pers = Liste->pers;


            Tempo->suivant = L;

            L = Tempo;

        }

        Liste = Liste->suivant;
    }


    *P = L;
}

/*___________________________________________________________________
*/

void main() {

    /* Écrivez les déclarations des 2 nouvelles listes ici */
    pointeur ListeF, ListeM ;


    pointeur liste ;

    /* question 6 */

    struct Personne Tempo;
    char NomTempo[LONG_NP+1];

    creerFIFO(&liste);
    afficher(liste, "FIFO");

    /* Écrivez les appels de la fonctions de la
       question 6 ici, le bon résultat sera observé
       avec la relecture de metrique.bin
    */

    strcpy(Tempo.nomPre,"BEDARD MARC-ANDRE             ");
    Tempo.sexe = 'M';
    Tempo.taille = 1.54;
    Tempo.poids = 0;

    cherModif(liste,Tempo.nomPre,Tempo);

    strcpy(NomTempo,    "TREMBLAY CYLVAIN              ");

    strcpy(Tempo.nomPre,"TREMBLAY SYLVAIN              ");
    Tempo.sexe = ' ' ;
    Tempo.taille = 0;
    Tempo.poids = 0;

    cherModif(liste,NomTempo,Tempo);


    creerBinaire(liste, "metrique.bin");

    relire("metrique.bin");


    /* Écrivez les appels pour la question 7 ici */

    CreerLIFO(liste,&ListeF,'F');
    CreerLIFO(liste,&ListeM,'M');



    /* Pour tester, écrivez 2 appels de la fonction
       afficher : */
    afficher(ListeF,"LIFO");
    afficher(ListeM,"LIFO");

}
```